# How to query wikimedia commons images with descriptions?

Tags: javascript, wikipedia-api, wikimedia

I'm trying to build a gallery of sorts so that my user can search for images on various topics that are in the public domain.  I'm trying to pull down a list of images from wikimedia but with their descriptions or "alt" descriptions.  I can't figure out from the docs how to do that.  Here's the api url I've managed to piece together so far from research.  For example all images of "Lewis Hayden":

[action=query&prop=imageinfo|categories&generator=search&gsrsearch="Lewis Hayden"&origin=*](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo%7Ccategories&generator=search&gsrsearch=%22Lewis%20Hayden%22&format=jsonfm&origin=*)

From this I get the url from which I can then build an  tag for the images. But I can't get the description or the title of the picture.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

[action=query&prop=imageinfo|categories&generator=search&gsrsearch=File:Lewis&iiprop=extmetadata&iiextmetadatafilter=ImageDescription|ObjectName](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo%7Ccategories&generator=search&gsrsearch=File:Lewis&format=jsonfm&origin=*&iiprop=extmetadata&iiextmetadatafilter=ImageDescription%7CObjectName)

The File: search keyword will make it search images instead of pages; `iiprop=extmetadata` will expose image metadata (like description).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get images with descriptions and thumbnails from wikimedia commons, you can use this javascript library https://github.com/tbo47/ez-opendata

It wraps the REST calls to wikimedia commons into a simple javascript or typescript functions.

```js
const northEast = { lat: 14.71, lng: -17.41 };
const southWest = { lat: 14.67, lng: -17.47 };
const images = await wikimediaQuery(northEast, southWest);
```

A link to play with the API: https://jsfiddle.net/tbo47/hyrn2vc0/